# How to auto indent a ruby code in linux

Tags: ruby, linux, vim, auto-indent

I am searching for a means of auto indent a ruby code in linux. I tried installing VIMFILES but not able to figure out how to use that.
Please if anyone know how to fix it , lemme know about that.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) to install Vim plugins. Just download it

```
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

then add to your `~/.vimrc`

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

# Your plugins
Plugin 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

Then restart Vim and run `:PluginInstall`. After restarting again, you can auto-indent Ruby files via

```
gg=G
```